# How does YARN manage containers and jvm-s for Spark partitions?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, partition

I am not clear on how spark partitions and yarn containers are related. If I have 3 nodes (--num-executors = 3), and 10 partitions, does yarn create a total of 10 containers (each one a jvm, if I understand correctly), and spread them over the 3 nodes? Does the resource manager ever start one container for a partition and then reuse it for the next partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/apache-spark-resource-management-and-yarn-app-models/) *Cloudera* post:

> When running Spark on YARN, each Spark executor runs as a YARN container. Where MapReduce schedules a container and fires up a JVM for each task, Spark hosts multiple tasks within the same container. This approach enables several orders of magnitude faster task startup time.

As I understand, *YARN* creates a container per executor, which is then assigned to several tasks in parallel or sequentially. Regarding to your example, *YARN* would create a total of 3 containers, assigning an average of 3-4 tasks (one per partition) to each one.

Couriously, what you describe is the common behavior of the *MapReduce* architecture.

Comment: Well, interesting. I certain am right about one thing, that is there is a architectural design decision to be made here.

Comment: but will these tasks run parallel or sequentially?

Comment: @dhruven1600 The *in parallel or sequentially* part might not be too clear. The containers are executed in parallel, each in a different executor. Each container, however, can only run one task in a given moment of time.

Comment: So can we say that in each container, each task (partition) will run on separate JVM? **When running Spark on YARN, each Spark executor runs as a YARN container. Where MapReduce schedules a container and fires up a JVM for each task, Spark hosts multiple tasks within the same container.** from the Cloudera post.

Comment: @dhruven1600 While *MapReduce* fires up a **JVM for each task**, *YARN* fires up a **JVM for each container**; this containers run multiple tasks (partitions) with the same JVM.